# Linq add order by to existing selectMany

Tags: c#, linq

I have a form with a groupbox. In this groupbox I have 3 other groupboxes. Each groupbox has at least 1 button.

I have 1 button in the parent groupbox which should do a perform click on all buttons in the child groupboxes.

This part I have working, but now the order is based on the design-time placement order of the buttons.

Because all child groupboxes are below each other I thought to order by Location.Y to start with the first button. But I can't get this to work. It keeps starting with the last button.

This is my LINQ which is working:

```
var groups = parentBox.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>();

foreach (var button in
         groups.Select(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<Button>())
               .SelectMany(buttons =>
                     buttons.Where(button => button.Tag != null
                                             && button.Tag.ToString() == "run")))
{
    button.PerformClick();
}
```

I already understand I need to add *.OrderByDescending(button => button.Location.Y)* somewhere but my attempts didn't work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option you have that *may* be a little more reliable and flexible than the Y-position of the buttons is the [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property for controls. You can set this up ahead of time (design) and then order based on that. Your users will also get the added benefit of being able to `TAB` through the buttons in your defined order.

Also keep in mind, sometimes it helps to break a complex LINQ expression into a few sub-expressions, even just for debugging purposes. Something like:

```
var groups = parentBox.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>();

var buttons = groups.SelectMany(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<Button>());

var buttonsWithRunTag = buttons.Where(button => button.Tag != null && button.Tag.ToString() == "run");

var orderByTabIndex = buttonsWithRunTag.OrderBy(button => button.TabIndex);

foreach (var button in orderByTabIndex)
{
   button.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. I first started with sub-expressions but I use ReSharper and it suggested to change it. Normally this is no problem but this time I needed to add something and with the complicated LINQ I had it was too difficult for. I also understand now how to solve these kind of issues in the future. I will mark your answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is due to the fact that control locations are always relative to the top corner of their *direct* parent. So you have to order by the `GroupBox` positions and then by the `Button` positions within the boxes:

```
var buttons = parent.Controls
                    .OfType<GroupBox>()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Top)
                    .SelectMany(gb => gb.Controls.OfType<Button>()
                                       .OrderBy(x => x.Top))
                    .Where(button => button.Tag != null
                                  && button.Tag.ToString() == "run"))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Gert Arnold. You're right as well. I use the TabIndex now as suggested by Kaveman and split my LINQ into several sub-expressions.